# ORACLE: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate(3.0) + Oracle DB (10g) for my application.

My domain object are like PluginConfig.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plugin_config" , schema = "test")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage =org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Config {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1959019321092627830L;

/** This object's id */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "plugin_id")
private Plugin plugin;

@Column(name = "config_name")
@NaturalId(mutable = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "config_desc")
private String description;
```

another domain object Plugin.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plugin", schema = "test")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Plugin implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5694761325202724778L;

/** This object's id */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected long id;

@Column(name = "plugin_name")
@NaturalId
private String pluginName;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "plugin_config_id")
private PluginConfig pluginConfig;

@Column(name = "plugin_desc")
private String description;
```

Whenever i try to load Plugin via my database service method(using @Transactional annotation and hence it loads all its children as well) i get the following error

> org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [PluginConfig#53]

There is actually no row in plugin_config table with `id = 53`.
And also no plugin table entry has `plugin_config_id=53`.

So from where is hibernate picking these values ?
I noticed one thing here, the value "53" is actually the row number from the plugin_config table which should have been reffered.

See the below image:

[image]

This is the plugin config that my query should be looking for. But it tries to search it with identifier #53(Row no:) instead of the #95(value of the primary key "id").

Where can i be going wrong with this ?

Comment: See the image here!


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hVpob.png

Comment: Does the corresponding object based on the `plugin_config_id` exists at all? How are you trying to load the entity in the `plugin_config` table?

Comment: How are you generating your table id's?

Comment: @c.s. : Yes! the object based on plugin_config_id exists with identifier #95 but not with #53(which hibernate is looking for).

Comment: I'm loading the plugin_config(Child object) by loading plugin(Parent object) via hibernate criteria. The method with criteria has @Transactional annotation with it.

Comment: I'm generating the ID using the hibernate @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) annotation. The column "id" is the primary key. The other value is not generated by my code. It is just the actual table row number shown by SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is teh best solution, but you can use `@NotFound` annotation with `IGNORE` command to let Hibernate discard exception adn set `pluginConfig` to `null`.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "plugin_config_id")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private PluginConfig pluginConfig;
```

Comment: Sadly that's not an option for me. in this particular case i could have gone for this, but i have a whole application where i'm facing the same issue. i need some other workaround for this.